# React onChange on input rerenders whole component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, setstate, use-state

My component rerenders and loses focus on the input everytime I type, I have all the same issues with any inputs.

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
<Input value={email} onChange={e=>setEmail(e.target.value)} type="email" />
```

Im using Chakra UI, Framer Motion, Redux, and react routers

Comment: can you share a reproducible demo?

Comment: Where does Input come from? That it rerenders is normal but it shouldn't lose focus. See https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-swanson-ozf7v

Comment: Looks correct. Maybe you need to share code of the whole page.

Comment: I haven't hooked up the backend  with the front end so it should work fine.
https://github.com/kgcusi/metroville
The components that has the inputs are Login.js and Register.js

Comment: it doesnt do anything yet just want to solve why the onChange and setState inside the input refreshes the whole component.

Comment: @kgcusi that simply how React works. Changing state triggers a rerender

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-dew-cf5wr?file=/src/App.js this is a reproducible sandboox ifi u would like to check

Comment: @kgcusi can't reproduce the behaviour you describe in your codesandbox

Answer (score -1):

Re-rendering is normal, this is how [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) behave.
Losing focus might have to do with the rest of your application. Try adding [`autofocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/autofocus) and see if it's solves your problem.

---

If you don't want to re-render on every update, want to control `focus` etc, use an [uncontrolled-component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), which uses [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to access DOM elements directly.

Example from official docs:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.input = React.createRef();  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.input.current.value);    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" ref={this.input} />        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```